What's the thermodynamic effect of cooling headbands worn at the 2024 Olympic marathon?
At this year's Olympic Marathon, athletes were wearing "cooling headbands" as shown here by an image of Sifan Hassan, the winner of the Women's event:

Sifan Hassan winning the 2024 Olympic Marathon (AP Photo/Dar Yasin).
I'd be curious to hear some thoughts on the thermodynamic effects of this. The company that sells these headbands (I don't want to link to it, but I'm sure you can find it if you look for it) states this in their FAQ:

How does the technology work?
When water or sweat evaporates on the
surface of the skin it absorbs heat and cools the body.
The amplified cooling effect of the Omius technology comes from water
being absorbed into the cooling pieces where it has 5x more surface
area for evaporation. The transformation of water from a liquid to a
gas on the surface of the graphite pulls heat from the inside of the
cooling pieces which are in contact with the skin and thus cooling the
skin.
Because the cooling effect is driven solely by water evaporation the
effect will continue indefinitely as long as the cooling pieces are
wet and have airflow across them.

Would it be possible to come up with a simple napkin calculation that compares the cooling effect of sweating with and without wearing the headband?
Is it as simple as saying that for a surface area $A$ of the human body, this simply adds $5 \cdot A_{\text{headband}}$ to the surface area and the cooling effect is proportional to that?

One reason the effect will probably be less than simply adding the headband area to the skin surface area is that the sweat in the headband is not in direct contact with the body. This means that evaporation will be using less latent heat from the body, and more from the air and headband.

I noticed a publication with the title: Assessment of the OmiusTM cooling headband during a 70-minute submaximal running effort followed by a 5-km time-trial in hot/humid conditions In a quick glance I noticed mention of 'metal towers' that are designed to act as thermal conductors. That would mean that the latent heat that goes to the evaporation will be drawn from the body.

Interesting report. The abstract ends with "We  conclude  that  in  hot/humid  conditions, [the headband] does  not  improve  heart  rate, forehead and rectal temperatures,  perceived  exertion,  whole-body  and  forehead  thermal comfort  and  performance  during  a  5-km  running  [time trial]  preceded  by  70  min  of  moderate-intensity running."
